# Highlighting Text in a Textbox Using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a web page that prompts for user input in a textbox.  I would like to display a default line of text in this box but highlight it so that the user input will automatically overwrite it.  I was told in another thread to use JQuery and this is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="D:jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#MessagesTextbox").select();
    });
</script>
```

Of course it is not doing the desired trick.  I am very new to JQuery -- and web programming in general -- and I would appreciate any advice.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Combine both `select()` and `focus()`:

```
$('#MessagesTextbox').focus().select();​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9zaq6/).

If you're able, though, it'd be even easier to use the `placeholder` attribute for the `textarea`:

```
<textarea id="MessagesTextbox" placeholder="Some default text"></textarea>​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9zaq6/1/).

And the following jQuery:

References:

- [`focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/).
- [`placeholder` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/input#attr-placeholder).
- [`select()`](http://api.jquery.com/select/).

Comment: I don't have access to the placeholder attribute in ASP.NET it seems.  Also, I tried the first suggestion but it didn't work.

Comment: The page loaded no problem but the text was not highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Try This - $('#MessagesTextbox').focus(function() { this.select(); });

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are after, but check this link out: [watermark plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/). It's a jquery plugin for watermarks.

You'll have to download the `jquery.watermark-3.1.3.js`, and then all you do is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#MessagesTextbox").watermark('Required information');
})
```

**Edit**

I re-read it, and if you are just looking to put focus on the field, then yes,
    `$("#MessagesTextbox").focus();` is what you are looking for, and added the link.